# NIFI insert large CSV into SQL Database

Tags: csv, apache-nifi

I'm trying to insert large quantites of large CSV files into a database.
I'm doing this with the PutDataBaseRecord processor, which makes this process really fast and easy.

The problem is that I don't know how to handle failures properly, e.g. if a value doesn't match a column's datatype or if a row is a duplicate.
If such a thing occurs, the PutDataBaseRecord processor discards all the records of the batch it just converted from the CSV file. So if one record of 2.000.000 fails, none of the 2.000.000 records make it into the db.

I managed to fix one problem source through cleaning the CSV data beforehand, but I still run into the issue of duplicate rows.

This I attempted to fix by splitting the CSV into single rows inside NIFI before passing them into the PutDatabaseRecord processor, which is really really slow and often results in a OOM error.

Can someone suggest an alternative way of inserting large CSVs in a SQL database?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to use [ValidateCsv](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.7.1/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ValidateCsv/index.html) or [ValidateRecord](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.7.1/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ValidateRecord/index.html) to do the datatype stuff and other validation. Detecting duplicates in huge files is difficult since you have to keep track of everything you've seen, which can take a lot of memory. If you have a single column that could be used for detecting duplicates, try ValidateCsv with a Unique constraint on that column, and set the Validation Strategy to line-by-line. That should keep all valid rows together so you can still use PutDatabaseRecord afterward.

Alternatively, you can split the CSV into single rows (use at least two SplitText or SplitRecord processors, one to split the flow file into smaller chunks, followed by a second that splits the smaller chunks into individual lines) and use DetectDuplicate to remove duplicate rows. At that point you'd likely want to use something like MergeContent or MergeRecord to bundle rows back up for more efficient use by PutDatabaseRecord